# European bank account

Tags: eu-citizens, banking, job-hunting, salary, money-transfer

I am looking for a good bank account with mobile banking. I move a lot and have clients from e.g. Spain and Italy. I am an EU citizen and mostly move around the Eurozone. There is no point in opening n bank accounts in n countries, since I would not be able to keep track of it.

I prefer EUR and SEK accounts, since these currencies are AFAIK fairly stable.
I was thinking about using PayPal or an equivalent to receive my salary, but that would feel rather uncomfortable, I think. Most companies are obliged to keep track of their spending, therefore they require some kind of bank connection if you want to come work for them.

I heard about Nemea Bank and similar institutions taking the innovative approach, but some of them seem... unreliable.

http://www.maltatoday.com.mt/business/business_news/64780/nemea_bank_releases_annual_figures_were_profitable_and_highly_liquid

What's your experience with that? Any sensible recommendations?

Comment: What language / languages are you looking to operate the account in?

Comment: @Gagravarr I would prefer English, but it does not matter too much to me.

Comment: I may not know a representative sample, but [Citibank UK multi-currency accounts](https://www.citibank.co.uk/personal/current-accounts.do) (free if you pay enough in each month) and German-based [Number 26](https://number26.eu/) seem the most popular with those I know in your sort of situation